# Which clone brand and set do these pieces belong to, rock platforms and castle walls?

Tags: piece-information, clone-brands

[image]
[image]

Please help. What set is the rock platforms from and the other rock pieces? The castle walls too?

Answer (score 2):

Most of these are mixed Mega bloks Dragons sets from the Dragons series.

The rock platforms are from [Dragons: Raiders Keep #9650](http://www.blokcity.com/wiki/9650_Raiders_Keep)  ([more pictures](https://www.2ememain.be/jouets-jeux/jouets/autres-jeux/megabloks-s%C3%A9rie-dragons-iron-225812601.html)).

[image]

There is also a window from [#9885 Marauder's Cliff](http://www.blokcity.com/wiki/9885_Marauder%27s_Cliff).
[image]